# Issue with bash script setting parent folder permissions also

Tags: linux, bash, file-permissions

I have a bash script that takes in parameters of a file/folder, the numbered permissions, user and group.

It determines if the path variable is either a file or a folder and sets the permissions accordingly.

The issue is when I pass in a folder, it sets the files within **and** the folder itself to the new user and group.

How can I set just the files in the loop **and not the folder**

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
ocatal=$2
user=$3
group=$4
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
if [ $2 -gt 766 ]
then
   tput setaf 1
   echo -e "${RED}777 is not allowed!!! :-("
   tput sgr0
   exit 1   
else
    if [ -f "$path" ] 
    then
        chmod $2 $1
        chown ${3:=$(/usr/bin/id -run)}:$4 $1 
        tput setaf 2
        echo Permission set to $2
        echo User set to $3
        echo Group set to $4
        echo `ls -l $1`
    else
        for f in $path/*
        do
            chmod $2 $f
            chown ${3:=$(/usr/bin/id -run)}:$4 $f 
            tput setaf 2
            echo Permission set to $2
            echo User set to $3
            echo Group set to $4    
        done
        echo `ls -l $1`
    fi
   exit 0
fi
```

Comment: "echo \`ls -l $1\`" is just useless use of `echo`, just `ls -l "$1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue is when I pass in a folder, it sets the files within and the
>   folder itself to the new user and group.

This is happening because of this pattern `$path/*` also expands to just $path/ and this causing change of folder perms. `*` means any file(symbol) or nothing, so $path is also in list.

Update, i wasn't quite right here, looks like this issue is taking place only if given folder is empty, here is test echo with an empty dir

```
$ echo testdir/*
testdir/*
```

And with files

```
$ echo testdir/*
testdir/file testdir/file2
```

Consider this

```
[[  -d "$path" ]] && {
    cd "$path"
    chmod -f $ocatal *
    chown -f $user:$group *
    ...
    cd - # back to previous folder
}
```

`-f` to suppress error messages in case of empty folder

And add this code `DEF='\e[0m'` to your colors to set default coloring.

```
echo -e "${RED}777 is not allowed!!! :-($DEF"
```

Comment: Question: does this replace the for loop code? I am assuming that -d is a check for directory? I'm still a bit fresh in Linux bash

Comment: Yes it is a check for directory, and if it's a direcrory `cd` to that directory and change perms to all files inside, than go back with `cd -`.

Comment: @Ivan : Your solution works, of course, but maybe you could also point out, why the approach used by the OP did not work.

Comment: @user1934428, updated the answer with explanation of this.

Comment: Many thanks @Ivan and user1934428 for the answer and clearing up the fault I had.

Comment: @user2702643, looks like it's not a full story, updated the answer.

Comment: @Ivan: I'm not really convinced by your statement "$path/* also expands to just $path/". For example, when I do a `echo $HOME/*`, my `$HOME/` is not on the list being generated.